# can not pass json array from PHP to JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have been trying to pass a simple array from PHP to JQuery.  Here is what I have as far as relevant functions in my HTML/JS:

```
function myQuery() {

 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "sandbox.php";

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   myFunc(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

}

function myFunc(response) {
 var arr = JSON.parse(response);
 document.getElementById("demco").innerHTML = arr[0];
}
```

For PHP I have tried:

```
<?php
 $arr = [4,7,2];
 echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

and:

```
<?php
 $arr = array(4,7,2);
 echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

According to my debugger it fails at JSON.parse(response) every time.  What is wrong in the code here?  I tried running the array, [4,7,2], through http://json.parser.online.fr/ and got no issues.  I'm at my wits end, help me SE!

EDIT:

From the console:
parse error in PHP on line X
Where X is the line containing:
    $arr = [4,7,2];
Uncaught exception: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Unable to parse value:

Error thrown at line Y, column 2 in myFunc(response) in http://...
   var arr = JSON.parse(response);
called from line Z, column 4 in () in http://localhost/sandbox.html:
   myFunc(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: `console.log(response)` my guess is it has more than just json.

Comment: are u using a framework or just static pages?

Comment: It works on my Apache2 server. What exact error are you getting when it fails at `JSON.parse` and what does `console.log(response)` give you?

Comment: updated OP with log results.  was not able to resolve the issue but I created another .php file with virtually the same contents and it worked.  now I am having the same problem with another JSON object on a different project.  what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a doctype tag at the top of the PHP file which was being passed with the JSON, and was screwing up the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Set output page header to application/json to do it clearly.
It is required to make output only in JSON code.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$arr = array(4,7,2);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This will make pure JSON output and it will be easily readable by Javascript